# LinkedIn Login for ASP.NET MVC 5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with an `ASP.NET MVC 5` web application. I need to provide the users to login with their `LinkedIn` accounts. MVC 5 provides the support for Login with Facebook, Google. But I don't have a clear idea of how to implement this with LinkedIn.

There isn't any Katana support for LinkedIn in MVC 5. What would be the approach should I take to implement this specific behavior in MVC 5? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to do it successfully..! I duplicate the code used for the implementation of Facebook authentication in Owin/Katana. You can find it here.

[Katana Project Source Code](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README)

I copied all the files and the folder indicated inside the red box in the following picture.

[image]

Paste them in my own MVC 5 Web application project where I need to implement LinkedIn authentication. Renamed all the classes as LinkedIn instead of Facebook.

[image]

And then I changed the code to adapt it to LinkedIn.

1. Constants Class
   Changed the DefaultAuthenticationType to LinkedIn instead of Facebook.
2. LinkedInAuthenticationHandler class

   ```
   private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
   private const string GraphApiEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~";
   ```

   Change this code inside ApplyResponseChallengeAsync method.

   ```
   string authorizationEndpoint =
               "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization" +
                   "?response_type=code" +
                   "&client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Options.AppId) +
                   "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri) +
                   "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(scope) +
                   "&state=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(state);
   ```
3. LinkedInAuthenticationOptions Class

   ```
   CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin");
   ```

Then go to Startup.Auth.cs file in App_Start folder in your project and add this code in it.

```
    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(
            APIKey: "...YourLinkedInAPIKeyHere...",
            SecretKey: "...YourLinkedInSecretKeyHere..."
            );
```

provide your application details to the LinkedIn API as well. You can read more details about it from here.

[Using LinkedIn Authentication](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

That's all. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't specific to MVC 5, but there's a couple of links here on how to implement LinkedIn oAuth.

[`Custom oAuth LinkedIn Provider`](http://blog.mrroa.com/post/30454808112/asp-net-custom-linkedin-oauth-provider)

[`DotNetOpenAuth for MVC`](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/), using LinkedIn

Also, I just came across this on SO, [LinkedIn full profile details using DotNetOpenAuth in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610026/linkedin-full-profile-details-using-dotnetopenauth-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 3):

As some time has passed since the OP, a more straightforward solution IMHO is to use to the [`Owin.Security.Providers` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/).

Once the package is added to your solution, the use of LinkedIn as a provider is very easy as explain on [the author blog](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/guides/aspnet-mvc-linkedin-login/).

And, on top of the fact that the project is [open sourced](https://github.com/owin-middleware/OwinOAuthProviders), the bonus is that you get at the same time the support for other authentication providers such as GitHub, Yahoo or StackExchange :o)